# Customize related objects for many-to-many field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many

There are games entity, each of them could have 1 or more platforms. Also each game could have 1 or more links to related games (with their own platforms). Here it looks like in **models.py**:

```
class Game(TimeStampedModel):
    gid = models.CharField(max_length=38, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    platforms = models.ManyToManyField(
        Platform, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    #here is the self-referencing m2m field
    related_games = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", related_name="related", blank=True)
```

And this model are served with this code in **admin.py**:

```
@admin.register(Game)
class GameAdmin(AdminImageMixin, reversion.VersionAdmin):
    list_display = ("created", "name", "get_platforms"... )
    list_filter = ("platforms", "year",)
    #I'm interested in changing the field below
    filter_horizontal = ("related_games",)

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {"widget": CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }

    def get_platforms(self, obj):
        return ", ".join([p.name for p in obj.platforms.all()])
```

I need to extend **filter_horizontal = ("related_games",)** part of admin.py - to add a platform information of each game in related games widget. It should look like (game name and platforms list): "Virtual Fighter (PS4, PSP, PS3)".

The application uses Django 1.7 and Python 2.7

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, what is shown for each item in a `filter_horizontal` is based on the object's `__str__` or `__unicode__` method, so you could try something like the following:

```
class Game(TimeStampedModel):
    # field definitions
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(
            self.name,
            (', '.join(self.platforms.all()) if self.platforms.exists()
                else 'none')
        )
```

This will make each game show in the list (and everywhere else) as "Name (Platforms)", for example "Crash Bandicoot (PS1, PS2)" or "Battlefield (none)" if it doesn't have any platforms

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the `__unicode__` method of your model, you'll need to set your `ModelAdmin` to use a custom `ModelForm`, specifying that the `related_games` field should use a custom `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with a custom `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget, in which you will need to override the `render_options` method. The following classes should be in their respective separate files, but it would look something like:

```
# admin.py

class GameAdmin(AdminImageMixin, reversion.VersionAdmin):
    # ...
    form = GameForm
    # ...


# forms.py

from django import forms

class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    related_games = RelatedGamesField()

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'gid',
            'name',
            'platforms',
            'related_games',
        )


# fields.py

from django.forms.models import ModelMultipleChoiceField

class RelatedGamesField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    widget = RelatedGamesWidget()


# widgets.py

from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class RelatedGamesWidget(FilteredSelectMultiple):
    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        # slightly modified from Django source code
        selected_choices = set(force_text(v) for v in selected_choices)
        output = []
        for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
            if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
                output.append(format_html(
                    '<optgroup label="{0}">',
                    # however you want to have the related games show up, eg.,
                    '{0} ({1})'.format(
                        option_value.name,
                        (', '.join(option_value.platforms.all())
                            if option_value.platforms.exists() else 'none')
                    )
                ))
                for option in option_label:
                    output.append(self.render_option(selected_choices, *option))
                output.append('</optgroup>')
            else:
                output.append(self.render_option(selected_choices, option_value, option_label))
        return '\n'.join(output)
```

Comment: And what if such functionality needed only in admin part and only related to horizontal filter widget? I'm new to this project and suppose, that changing __unicode__ part could break some stuff.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an alternative instead of overriding `__unicode__`, though it's definitely not as succinct

Comment: First variant with __unicode__ works fine. Except join method need strings, except of objects. So I've done it like this: ' '.join([unicode(p) for p in self.platforms.all()])